# Simplify yaml routing rules for appengine (python)

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, app.yaml

I have 17 files in a images folder. I have created 17 rules for them, that I would like to simplify, i.e. make one rule that will work with regex or something else. Is there a way?

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: images/favicon.ico
  upload: images/favicon.ico

- url: /apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
  static_files: images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
  upload: images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png

- url: /apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
  static_files: images/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
  upload: images/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png

- url: /apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
  static_files: images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
  upload: images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png

  ...
```

I ended up using these rules:

```
- url: /(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))

- url: /(android-chrome.*\.(png))
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(android-chrome.*\.(png))

- url: /(mstile.*\.(png))
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(mstile.*\.(png))

- url: /(favicon-.*\.(png))
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(favicon-.*\.(png))

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: images/favicon.ico
  upload: images/favicon.ico
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google App Engine Boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/app.yaml):

```yaml
- url: /(\w*)/(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))
  static_files: bp_content/themes/\1/static/\2
  upload: bp_content/themes/(\w*)/static/(apple-touch-icon.*\.(png))
```

That's the relevant source for your needs, and you might also pick up a few more tricks :)